# Youtube iframe script returns 429

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Trying to load the script https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api from an html page but getting a 429.
This is a static script, why would google block these type of requests?
Obviously google flagged my IP for some reason.

Any suggestions on how to resolve it or at least avoid this from reoccurring once the flagging has been removed (timed out?).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope it's still relevant.

I had the same issue and i solved it by adding a timestamp (or any other random string) in the YouTube iFrame SDK URL of the script.

So instead of  `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` i did `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api?${Date.now()}` and it's working now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After a while the throttling block was removed, which fixed the issue. Regardless, when I reported the issue to Google, the representative said it's not an issue. Tried explaining to him that 429 should be for API calls and should not occur for static scripts. But the rep did not understand the explanation, and since it's working no point in additional back and forth.